# Matcher. Как использовать спецсимвол в качестве replacement?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, подскажите как через метод `appendReplacement` класса `Matcher` заменить найденную группу на спецсимвол? Например, здесь я пробую в качестве replacement передать строку `"$$$"`.
Полный пример:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(qwe)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("qwerty");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    m.find();
    m.appendReplacement(b, "$$$");
    m.appendTail(b);
    b.toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно экранировать символы `$` в строке-замене при помощи обратного слэша `\`, который в свою очередь следует экранировать в строках путём удвоения:

```java
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(qwe)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("qwerty");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    m.find();
    m.appendReplacement(b, "\\$\\$\\$");
    m.appendTail(b);
    
    System.out.println(b); // -> $$$rty
```